# Determine whether window handle is an appbar window

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, appbar

Is there a way to determine whether a window is an [appbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/application-desktop-toolbars) (application desktop toolbar)?

The Windows taskbar has the window styles `WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`. However, the presence of those window styles don't seem to guarantee that a window is an appbar.

Comment: Appbars aren't a special type of window, the only thing special is that the system knows about them and subtracts their size from the size of the desktop workspace. I don't think there's any API for enumerating or querying them, but you could probably infer them from their size and position (e.g. if they lie outside the `MONITORINFO.rcWork` area and are the full width or full height of the monitor.)

Comment: That sounds like it might be the best approach. What about fullscreen apps like games though? Also seems like appbars don't completely prevent normal windows from being outside of `rcWork` (eg. take a Notepad window and slide it underneath the taskbar and it'll still be report its position as outside of `rcWork`).

Comment: A fullscreen game will be >= 0 from ALL edges. Appbars can't. This should not matter to most apps since they should only care about the workarea (or screen if fullscreen).

Comment: UI Automation has specific support for appbar, so you should be able to identity an appbar using it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-supportappbarcontroltype

Comment: The UIA support works for [AppBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar) controls, WinUI's excuse for not offering menu bars.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would work reliably is to loop through all monitors and edges and retrieve their `hWnd`, using [`ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAREX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/abm-getautohidebarex)

Comment: @Charlieface Unfortunately `ABM_GETAUTOHIDEBAREX` only gets appbars that have auto-hide enabled. Tried it out to make sure. It's pretty strange how there's seemingly no method to get an appbar on a given edge that's not auto-hidden